# Mean Value Theorem for $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous and differentiable function on $[a, b]$. Then does there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $$\frac{|f(b) -f(a)|}{b - a} \leq |f'(c)|?$$

Comment: @sciona It's not stated that $f'$ is continuous or integrable.

Comment: @user208259 I thought the fundamental theorem of calculus told us that if $f$ is differentiable then $f'$ is integrable, do you have a counter-example in mind?

Comment: @sciona http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6711/integrability-of-derivatives The other problem is that you implicitly assume that $|f'|$ attains its maximum.

Comment: @user208259 Volterra function! many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

This is almost the same as the well-known mean value theorem for vector-valued functions. See 8.5.4 in Dieudonné's *Foundations of Modern Analysis*. The difference is that that theorem is stated in terms of $\sup |f'(t)|$, and in your case there is, at first glance, no guarantee that the sup is attained.

Nonetheless, with a slight additional argument, your form of the theorem can be proved. This is a special case of Problem 7 in the same section of the book. (In outline: Assume that you know that $|f(b) - f(a)| = M(b-a)$ and $|f'(t)| \leq M$ everywhere. If there's a point $c$ where $|f'(c)| < M$, you can basically show that $f$ wastes a bit of time on a small interval containing $c$, and then apply the ordinary mean value theorem outside that interval to reach a contradiction.)